# Target.address for multiple rows in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I need to reference an entire column of Excel spreadsheet, with a drop-down list using VBA. The code i got online works only for a single cell which is `"$M$2"`. How can i define  a range for the entire column?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

' To Select Multiple Items from a Drop Down List in Excel

Dim Oldvalue As String
Dim Newvalue As String

On Error GoTo Exitsub
If Target.Address = "$M$2" Then
    If Target.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation) Is Nothing Then
    GoTo Exitsub
    Else: If Target.Value = "" Then GoTo Exitsub Else
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Newvalue = Target.Value
        Application.Undo
        Oldvalue = Target.Value
        If Oldvalue = "" Then
            Target.Value = Newvalue
        Else
            Target.Value = Oldvalue & ", " & Newvalue
        End If
    End If
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True

Exitsub:
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: on my testing this code fails on the second undo attempt - your current error handling is masking this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, `Target` may be a single cell or multiple cells, depending on what the user changed

To test if any cell in (and only in) column M changed, use

```
If Target.EntireColumn.Address = "$M:$M" Then
```

To test if any cell in `Target` is in column M use

```
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Columns("M"))
If Not rng Is Nothing Then
```

Note: the rest of your code will need to be modified to allow for `Target` being more than one cell

Comment: while this answers the question as such, it doesn't address the error in the full code that occurs when Undo is run a second time.